# Change the colour of the app using alarm

Tags: android

I want to change the color and background of all the buttons and layouts in my android app as soon as it strucks 12am(i.e the day changes)

i should be able to do this using a alarm , whenever the alarm gives a feedback

or im calling a function it should change the colors & backgrounds but its not working.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(color.blue);
    rlbase.setBackgroundColor(color.green);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pi);
```

right now im changing these button color and background only but i intend to call a method from this alarm.

need some help

thanks

Comment: Could you put your code?

Comment: what you have tried so far..?

Comment: if any one could just tell me how to change the background of a activity whenever day changed or it 00:00:00 in 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://justcallmebrian.com/2010/04/27/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule-activities-on-android/

It may be useful for you.
Good luck!

Comment: thank you, but i believe i don't need a broadcast receiver to change the background of a activity, it is supposed to be changed if the user is using the app at 12am otherwise it will open with the changed background onstart of the activity